# Decipher part of a sweater pattern

Tags: knitting

I am knitting a vegetable-patterned sweater for my daughter, but have come to a part where I struggle with understanding the pattern. Perhaps someone can help me decode the instructions?

The pattern is originally in Swedish, and available [here](https://www.land.se/fixat/sticka-gronsakstrojan-till-den-lille-odlaren/). Google does a decent job at translating. The sweater is mostly knitted in the round, and I struggle understanding when one needs to start rounding for the neckline. Here's the exact excerpt (only including the size I'm knitting):

> When the armhole measures approx. 6 cm, start the neckline. Cast off the center front stitches. You must now switch to knitting back and forth. Cast off successively for the neckline 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 = 10 stitches. Knit the last stitch on the round with the base and pattern color yarn together. After the carrot pattern, continue to knit in one color with the base color until the armhole is 12cm. Now cast off 21 stitches in the center back and round for the neckline by casting off 3 stitches on each side. Then cast off the middle stitch in the armholes and skew for the shoulders: 13, 11, 10 = 34 stitches. Do not cast off but skew with turns and leave the stitches open. Place the stitches on each stitch holder.

My point of confusion is two things, firstly: the cast-off `3,3,2,1,1` I guess should go on the alternating sides of the front-stitches (that are to be cut later on). But isn't it odd that it's done assymmetrically? In the end, it would mean that 6 stitches are casted off on one side, and only 4 on the other. Any ideas why?

Secondly: after the cast-off in the center back, am I meant to start knitting back-and-forth first on the left-hand-side, and then on the right? Moreover, these `13,11,10`-cast-offs, where on earth are they places? Has anyone knitted something similar and have a clue of what is going on?

Comment: How many stitches do you have on the needles at the point where you're supposed to decrease for the neckline? That number can help interpret the rest of the pattern. Please [edit] your original question to add that information.